# JPA/HIBERNATE: Value must be a constant

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, enums

I have the following case.

```
public enum TestEnum{

    PUUNITONE("puunitone"),
    PUUNITTWO("puunittwo");

    private String name;

    private TestEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

in the `EJB @stateless` class

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = TestEnum.PUUNITONE.getName())
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

I have the following

```
Compilation Error: Value must be a constant
```

Now my question:

**1. In java are enums constants or not? If yes what is the problem here?

 2. Is there a way or workarround to solve this issue by using Enum as constant?**

Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Comment: Did you try it without "getName()"? Oracle docs says this: "...that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants". See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html.

Comment: May be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271659/use-enum-type-as-a-value-parameter-for-rolesallowed-annotation

Comment: @mwhs Thanks for your comment. unfortunately it doesn't work. The same error apprears

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, enums are constants, however `getName()` is not a constant : the compiler can't tell that it will always return the same result.
2. No, you have to use a litteral `String` or a `final static String` in the annotation. Only those are constants for the compiler.