# Referring value which is in enum within annotation?

Tags: java, enums, java-ee-7

I have written my custom annotation and is working fine if i use it as below.

```
@MyAnnotation("sun")
public void getResult(String id){


}
```

### MyAnnotation.java

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    String value();

}
```

above code is working fine. Now instead of hard coding "sun", i would like to keep it in an Enum as below.

```
public enum WeekDay{

    SUNDAY("sun"), MONDAY("mon");

    private String day;

    WeekDay(String day) {
        this.day= day;
    }


    public String getDay() {
        return this.day;
    }

}
```

and now with in annotation i do as below.

```
@MyAnnotation(WeekDay.SUNDAY.getDay())
    public void getResult(String id){


    }
```

above code gives compilation error in eclipse. It says **The value for annotation attribute MyAnnotation.value must be a constant expression**. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show us the Annotation code? Also, have you tried WeekDay.SUNDAY without .getDay() ?

Comment: Silviu, i edited my question. I tried your suggestion it says cannot convert from WeekDay to String.

Comment: Maybe declaring final the getDay() method?

Comment: Jorge, i tried. Still same problem..

Comment: @Jorge_B check my answer to see why it isn't working with final on getDay()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from :

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    String value();

}
```

To:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    WeekDay value();

}
```

And use it like this:

```
@MyAnnotation(WeekDay.SUNDAY)
```

It will also work if you pass a string literal to your current annotation. Marking your method as final won't work because final on methods only prevents you from overriding it, not returning a constant value.
Example:

```
public final String getString() {
  String[] strings = { "A", "B" };
  return strings[new Random().nextInt(2)]; // returned value is not the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All annotation properties are evaluated and set at compile time.  The method getDay() obviously has to wait until the code actually runs to return a value, so you can't use it to set things during compilation!

You can change the type of the Annotation's value to your enum and then simply supply the enum if you want.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
  Weekday value();
}

@MyAnnotation(WeekDay.SUNDAY)
public void getResult(String id){
}
```

but that might not make any sense if it's meant to accept a broader range of values.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. You can see an explanation in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3272859/1912167

However, you can define the annotation to only accept the enum:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    WeekDay value();

}

@MyAnnotation(WeekDay.SUNDAY)
public void getResult(String id){


}
```