# How to map all values of an enum to constant expression?

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hibernate-validator

I want to add all available values of an enum to a `hibernate validation` message. But I can't, as it expects a constant expression.

```
@NotNull(message = "Allowed values: " + MyEnum.values());
```

Result error:

```
The value for annotation attribute NotNull.message must be a constant expression
```

How can this be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253624/how-to-supply-enum-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-in-java#answer-13253879

Comment: You can not, but you can create a custom constraint to validate against MyEnum values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done. See also [Use Enum type as a value parameter for @RolesAllowed-Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271659/use-enum-type-as-a-value-parameter-for-rolesallowed-annotation).

Basically a compile-time constant expressions needs to be passed to `message`. See also [JSL section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).