# Concatenate string and variable in sec:authorize thymeleaf tag

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying use the thymeleaf tag sec:authorize like that:

```
sec:authorize="hasPermission(#user, 'listagem_${item.simpleName}')"
```

but when I deploy and run the project, the string `listagem_${item.simpleName}` is not processed and the content is not displayed because this.

Anyone know the right way to be able to do this concatenation inside the sec:authorize tag?

**UPDATE**

after try this:

```
<span th:text="|hasPermission(#user, 'listagem_${item.simpleName}')|"></span>
```

and see I get the right result, I try transport the expression: `|hasPermission(#user, 'listagem_${item.simpleName}')|` to the sec:authorize tag like this:

```
<li th:each="item : ${menu}" sec:authorize="|hasPermission(#user, 'listagem_${item.simpleName}')|">
```

but I get this error:

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: An error happened trying to parse Spring Security access expression "|hasPermission(#user, 'listagem_${item.simpleName}')|" (private/home:40)] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1069E:(pos 0): missing expected character '|'
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.Tokenizer.process(Tokenizer.java:194)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.Tokenizer.<init>(Tokenizer.java:84)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:121)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:60)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:32)
        at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:76)
        at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:62)
        at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.auth.AuthUtils.authorizeUsingAccessExpression(AuthUtils.java:186)
        at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.processor.AuthorizeAttrProcessor.isVisible(AuthorizeAttrProcessor.java:100)
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractConditionalVisibilityAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractConditionalVisibilityAttrProcessor.java:58)
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
        at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1016)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:971)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:672)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:655)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
        at org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

what I am missing here?

Comment: Have you tried ${'listagem_'+item.simpleName} ?

Comment: @MartinFrey yes, don't work either.

Comment: is listagem_ a separate variable you are passing as well? if it is then proper concat would be ${'listagem_'}+${item.simpleName}

Comment: @Aeseir this don't work. I get the error: `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 22): Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'lcurly({)'`.

Comment: so is listagem_ a variable you passing in, as i haven't seen it before in code

Comment: @Aeseir no, `listagem_` is a string literal, `item.simpleName` is a string variable.

Comment: Gotcha, try this |hasPermission(#user, 'listagem_'+${item.simpleName})|, technically that is sound and should work.

Comment: @Aeseir copy and past this and get the error: `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1069E:(pos 0): missing expected character '|'`. the code: `<li th:each="item : ${menu}" sec:authorize="|hasPermission(#user, 'listagem_'+${item.simpleName})|">...</li>`

Answer (score 2):

I have been having similar issues with string concatenation and the `sec:authorize` attribute in thymeleaf, although not exactly the same circumstances it may be useful to others who come across this problem.

I want to restrict the visibility of certain elements based on user (principal) permissions. In this example I have a page showing customer details which can be accessed by other users but only "account managers" can see the email address. When I hard code the permission string everything works fine:

`<th:block sec:authorize="hasAuthority('VIEW_USER_EMAIL')">
   ...
</th:block>`

I'd rather not scatter random strings over my templates though as they are likely to be refactored at some point and it is error prone. I have a class containing a load of `public static final String` fields called `Permission`. I would have liked to use an `enum` but it's not possible to reference from an annotation such as `@PreAuthorize` or `@Secured` which I used elsewhere in the application [see this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271659/use-enum-type-as-a-value-parameter-for-rolesallowed-annotation).

The solution is to reference my `Permission` class from within the expression in the template. This can be achieved using the [SpEL type operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types) `T()`. I had quite a bit of trouble getting the syntax right through trial an error until finally this worked:

`<th:block sec:authorize="hasAuthority(T(com.example.app.Permission).VIEW_USER_EMAIL)">
   ...
</th:block>`

This now means an exception will be thrown if the `Permission` class or `VIEW_USER_EMAIL` field doesn't exist or if there was a typo. This is a vast improvement over failing silently and probably denying access.

Below are a few of my previous attempts before I got it working:

`sec:authorize="hasAuthority('${T(com.example.app.Permission).VIEW_USER_EMAIL}')"`
`sec:authorize="hasAuthority(${T(com.example.app.Permission).VIEW_USER_EMAIL})"`
`sec:authorize="${hasAuthority('T(com.example.app.Permission).VIEW_USER_EMAIL')}"`

It looks like the thymeleaf Spring Security Dialect strips of a leading `${` and trailing `}` from any expression you pass in and attempts to evaluate the whole expression which is why any form of concatenation probably doesn't work.

For reference, here is my `Permission` class:

`public final class Permission
{
    public static final String VIEW_USER_EMAIL = "VIEW_USER_EMAIL";
}`

Comment: I also came across another case where I needed to use a variable within an expression and had trouble escaping it, the solution was to use triple single quotes: `th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''' + someObject.permissionString + ''')')}"`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had the user role name inside a variable. I finally managed to make it work with

```
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole('''+objectDTO.roleName+''')')}"></div>
```

The idea came from here (note the double single quotes to escape the name) https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity#using-the-expression-utility-objects

Answer (score 0):

I`m adding custom security expression with signature
`hasProjectRole(int projectId, String role)`, and then use in thymeleaf next trick:

```
<tr th:each="projectId : ${projects.keySet()}" th:object="${projects.get(projectId)}">
   <th:block th:if="${#authorization.expression(#strings.concat('hasProjectRole(', projectId, ',''ROLE_ADMIN'')'))}">

     ... 

   </th:block>
</tr>
```