# Java Annotation - array of Objects or toString values

Tags: java, annotations, coding-style

I need to write an Annotation to exclude certain values from a result set.

**Background:**

Distinct values are selected from fields and are listed in a ComboBox. Some of the legacy values are Deprecated and I don't want to show them, even if they are returned by JDBC's `SELECT DISTINCT()`. It's like a mini-framework where people can build select queries by clicking values from ComboBoxes.

I tried the following (the code does not compile - commented lines are the ways I tried to solve the problem):

```
public enum JobType {
    //...
    S,
    //...
}

public @interface Exclude {
    Object[] values(); // Invalid type
    Enum[] values(); // Invalid type again
    String[] values(); // Accepts but see the following lines
}

@Table(name = "jobs_view")
public class JobSelectionView extends View {
    //...
    @Exclude(values = {JobType.S.toString()}) // Not a constant expression
    @Exclude(values = {JobType.S.name()}) // Not a constant expression ?!?!?!
    @Exclude(values = {"S"}) // Works but... come on!
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private JobType type;
    //...
}
```

I don't like using `{"S"}`, any suggestions?

Comment: You **must** use a compile time constant. That means **no** methods. You can use `JobType[]`.

Comment: But if declare JobType[] values() then I won't be able to reuse the @Exclude for other types of Enum.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271659/use-enum-type-as-a-value-parameter-for-rolesallowed-annotation

Comment: You can use `public static final` constants.

Comment: I tried to trick Java with 'public static final String S = JobType.S.name();' but it's more clever than that. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if declare `JobType[] values()` then I won't be able to reuse the `@Exclude` for other types of `Enum`.

This is the best way to do what you want, though. Here's the thing:

### The class `Enum` is, itself, meaningless.

It only gains meaning when subclassed. Let's say you want to add another filter, say `Color` (your own custom `Color` enum, not `java.awt.Color`). Obviously, the thing thing that your filtration class is doing is very different for filtering out `JobType` than it would be for filtering out `Color`!

Therefore, the best thing to do would be to have each different time of `enum` you're trying to filter in it's own argument, e.g.

```
public @interface Exclude {
    JobType[] jobs;
    Color[] colors;
    Foo[] foos;
    Quux[] quuxes;
}
```

This will accomplish two things:

1. Make it easy for you to do different filtration behavior for each different filter type.
2. Make the `@Excludes` annotation more legibile by sorting the different parameters into different groups.

---

The Javadoc for [`Enum.name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()) says:

> Returns the name of this `enum` constant, exactly as declared in its `enum` declaration. Most programmers should use the `toString()` method in preference to this one, as the `toString` method may return a more user-friendly name. **This method is designed primarily for use in specialized situations where correctness depends on getting the exact name, which will not vary from release to release.**

I suggest you try to tell the people in your company to read up on the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and explain why violating it would be particularly damaging in this case.

Comment: For me, the important thing was if someone is refactoring the Enum's members (or their name) with an IDE, then the final Strings wouldn't contain the right name()-s. But with your solution it won't happen. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @AdamHorvath the Javadoc specifically states that they think it is unlikely that people will be renaming enum constants... See [`Enum.name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()). That said, if you're worried about it, you could use `toString()` instead of `name()`, though of course that has its own risks.

Comment: True, with a reasonable application. But in our "crazy" company we use Enums extensively. The toString() changes even more often, as we attach human-readable names to it; like JobType.S.toString() is "Sample". If you specify EnumType.STRING on your columns than it remains somewhat manageable.

Comment: You could require that all the enums implement an `interface ImmutableName { String immutableName(); }` which is guaranteed not to change on IDE refactoring... but there would be no way to enforce people implementing the interface, nor actually guaranteeing that `immutableName` doesn't change. I'm making an edit to my answer now.