# Java annotation, Attribute value must be constant

Tags: java, annotations

I see in Java when I use annotation to a method like this is not possible. It gives "Attribute must be a constant"

```
private static final String CONSTANT = MyClass.class.getCanonicalName();


@Timed(CONSTANT) //Attribute value must be constant
@CircuitBreaker(name = CONSTANT) //Attribute value must be constant
public String something( String something ) {
```

To emphasize, I am using @Timed and @CircuitBreaker here as example. Many other annotations will yield the exact same issue.

How to do it in Java? I mean, I do not want to hardcode the value here like such.

```
@Timed("MyClass") @CircuitBreaker(name = "MyClass")
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3271659 .

Comment: Can you clarify your end goal?  Your proximate problem is that you want two annotations to have the same argument.  What is the reason you want to do that?  (Also, I don't see that passing `CONSTANT` explicitly is any worse than writing `"MyClass"` explicitly.)

Comment: In this snippet, I showed 2, but actually, it is some 20 (but imagine a large number) spread among the entire class. If I need to change from MyClass to MyClazz (I know control + replace exists) changing one variable is always preferred to manually changing things in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static final String CONSTANT = MyClass.class.getCanonicalName();
```

These are the modifiers: `private static final`

This is the data-type/object-type: `String`

This is the name of your constant/variable/object: `CONSTANT`

This is the initiator: `=`

This is the attribute: `MyClass.class.getCanonicalName();`

Your attribute is not a constant, hence you can't initiate your constant `CONSTANT`.